# How to see the followed publisher & developer pages?

Tags: steam

Steam recently added [own pages for publishers and developers](https://store.steampowered.com/developer) (central "hubs" for their games) which count the number of followers.

Can I see all followed parties at once like for [followed games](https://steamcommunity.com/my/followedgames/) and [groups](https://steamcommunity.com/my/groups)?

Answer (score 1):

The developer feature [is still being implemented](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/creator_homepage#1):

> Feature Currently in Open Beta 
>   
> This feature is currently in an open
>   beta, which means we're still working on it, but it's open to all
>   developers and publishers and visible to players.

As of now, AFAIK (based solely on lack of evidence to the contrary), **it is not possible to see a list of the developers and/or publishers that are followed.** 

I presume that, once it comes out of beta, an extra submenu will be inserted under 'Store'.

However, because there is not even a **quick access button** to the developers page, I cursorily implemented one in Steam. 

You can download the necessary files [here](http://joachimbeens.com/files/Steam_extra_buttons.zip).

To install, unpack (the folder inside) to the *Steam\skins* folder (default *C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\skins*), restart Steam, go to 'Steam' -> 'Settings' -> 'Interface', choose 'extra_buttons' from the third drop down menu (under 'Select the skin you wish Steam to use')..

[image: Select skin in Steam]

..and restart.

Now, under 'View', there should be two new buttons, including one that lets you go directly to the developers/publishers page.

[image: The additional buttons]